# Are there any performance enhancements by setting EnableTheming to false?

Tags: .net, asp.net, performance

I have a site that will not use theming.  But by default the value is set to true.  Does ASP.NET do a check everytime to see if I'm using themes.  Is there a performance hit?

Thanks!
paul

Comment: Why you want to check the theme all times. you need to check only once, So it will improve the performance. Implement it in [Page_PreInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to the question, but it could most likely be determined by using Reflector on the Microsoft assemblies surrounding this area. Just a thought, if you are truly curious.

Even if there is, it would not be very heavy, perhaps a microsecond or two per hit. Unless you are developing a Google scale site, I would not be worried about. And, set on the control level, it is a hit you will take whether you set to true or false, so there is no escape.